# Invalid login credentials when using Oracles OracleConnection but not Systems

Tags: c#, oracle

I use the following code to connect to Oracle database:

```
using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection cn =
           new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(
               "Data Source=abcSource;User Id=abcUserId;Password=abcPassword;"));
{ 
    cn.Open(); 
}
```

But I get this error

> invalid login credentials

While if I try the following code I succeed.

```
using (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection cn = 
           new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection(
               "Data Source=abcSource;User Id=abcUserId;Password=abcPassword;"));  
{  
   cn.Open();  
}
```

I dont understand, what is happening?

Comment: The second example has a semicolon at the end of the using statement effectively destroying the cn variable. Do you have another cn variable defined and initialized elsewhere?

Comment: No I dont have another cn variable.